# Three.js 3d Modal not Rendering

Tags: reactjs, three.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swj3k.png)

Iam facing an issue in using three.js with react js. i complete code and cross check several time there is logical error. the console says that the tags which i use doesn't match with react. but these tags are three js tags. now i think that the three js library is not install properly i install the package also but still facing error command {npm install --legacy-peer-deps three}

```
import { Suspense} from "react"
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber"
import { OrbitControls,Preload,useGLTF } from "@react-three/drei"

import CanvasLoader from '../Loader'
const Computers = () => {
  const computer = useGLTF('./desktop_pc/scene.gltf');
  return (
    <mesh>
      <hemisphereLight intensity={0.15} groundColor="black" />
      <pointLight intensity={1}/>
      <primitive object={computer.scene}/>
    </mesh>
  );
}
const ComputersCanvas = () => {
  return (
    <Canvas
     frameloop="demand"
     shadows
     camera={{position:[20,3,5],fov:25}}
     gl={{preserveDrawingBuffer:true}}
     >
      <Suspense fallback={<CanvasLoader/>}>
        <OrbitControls 
        enableZoom={false}
        maxPolarAngle={Math.PI/2}
        minPolarAngle={Math.PI/2}
        />
        <Computers/> 
      </Suspense>
      <Preload all/>
    </Canvas>
  );
}


export default Computers
```

```
// import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import {styles} from '../styles'
import {ComputersCanvas} from './canvas/index';

const Hero = () => {
  return (
    <section className='relative w-full h-screen mx-auto'>
      <div className={`${styles.paddingX} absolute inset-0 top-[120px] max-w-7xl mx-auto flex flex-row items-start gap-5`}>
        <div className='flex flex-col justify-center items-center mt-5'>
          <div className='w-5 h-5 rounded-full bg-[#915eff]'/>
          <div className='w-1 sm:h-80 h-40 violet-gradient'/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1 className={`${styles.heroHeadText} text-white`}>Hi, I'm <span className='text-[#915eff]'>Muzamil</span></h1>
          <p className={`${styles.heroSubText} mt-2 text-white-100`}>
            I develop 3D visuals, user<br className='sm:block hidden'/> interfaces and web applications.
          </p>
        </div>
        <ComputersCanvas/>  
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default Hero[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPllM.png)
```

i check code several times there is no logical issue i expect the solution for my prblm